# expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token

Tags: c++, linux

I am getting this error;

```
expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
```

For the following code;

```
void CLog::featureAvailable(const LogString_t* const featureName, const LogString_t* const additionalInfo) const
{
    if(NULL!=additionalInfo)
    {
        CLog.info(AV_LTPROF, additionalInfo); // error here
    }
    else
    {
        CLog.info(AV_LTPROF); // error here
    }
}
```

And I don't understand why?

Comment: This is not [tag:c]. If you think it is you should read a lot.

Comment: I know it is not. It wouldn't let me put c++ as a tag

Answer (score 1):

The class method shown

```
CLog::featureAvailable(/*...*/)
```

Indicates that `CLog` is a class, the syntax for accessing members without an instance variable is not the `.` operator, but the scope resolution operator `::`.

Hence;

```
Clog::info(AV_LTPROF, additionalInfo);
```

Or with an explicit `this`;

```
this->info(AV_LTPROF, additionalInfo);
```

Or with the implicit `this`;

```
info(AV_LTPROF, additionalInfo);
```

The `info()` method is not shown, so it is unclear if it is `static` or not.